# Is it possible to apply style changes to a specific value of an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a p that shows dozens of different texts on specific mouse events.
Is it possible to have just one of this texts displayed with a different style?

I made a function which changes p.style.attributes but this function have to fire everytime the text in p changes, so I'm asking if there is a smoother way to do this. Is possible to give style to a value?

Let's make clear example:

```
var text32 = "this text should be in blue and huge"
```

Is it possible to give style values to a var like that?

Comment: Yes, but without more info all I can say is "Yes" it's possible. Clarification, not a value but you'd put your style code into the listener/mouse events code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170714/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-text-which-dinamically-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `class` on text change on whichever text you want. I have created simple example below where I am changing the Text of `p` tag on click and showing the different style on 3rd one. Again, this is just a simple example and the trick is you can change the `Class` whenever you want.

See the Snippet below:

```js
var pTag = document.getElementById("pTag");
var currentIndex = 0;

var pText = ["This is Text 1", "This is Text 2", "This is Text 3", "This is Text 4", "This is Text 5"];
var pBold = [false, false, true, false, false];


pTag.addEventListener("click", function(){
 currentIndex++;
 
  if(currentIndex >= pText.length)
   currentIndex = 0;
    
  pTag.innerHTML = pText[currentIndex];
  
  if(pBold[currentIndex])
    pTag.classList.add("redBold");
  else
   pTag.classList.remove("redBold");
})
```

```css
p{
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select:none;
}
.redBold{
    color:red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<p id="pTag">Click Me!!!!!!</p>

<span>On click of Above p ("Click Me!!!!!"), it will change the text. When the text will be 'This is Text 3', it should be in Red and Bold.</span>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/L1b8znas/) also.

Answer (score 1):

You said you have a p tag with multiple elements. So the js should be

```js
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
if(p[i].innerHTML == "text huge blue"){
  p[i].style.color = "blue";
  p[i].style.font = "italic bold 20px arial,serif";
}

else
  p[i].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<p>text huge blue</p>
<p>text huge other things</p>
```

In this snippet you have an array made by all the elements in the document with "p" tag, which i assume is your case (otherwise is quite easy to edit this code to apply it to your needs). If the content is "text huge blue" then make p's content blue huge and italic, otherwise make it red. So I provided you two examples to see the difference.